# What does it mean?

Tags: translation

With the great search for plane debris currently taking place in La Reunion island, a metal has been found with what seems to be Chinese written on it (it **might** be a plane debris, but nobody can be sure of that), but I can't find what it means :
[image]

Can you help me ?

Thank you.

*EDIT : Full photo for context : http://www.clicanoo.re/IMG/jpg/-19054.jpg*

Comment: I think it says `兴宜`. Not sure what the significance of that is.

Comment: Here you go: http://news.ifeng.com/a/20150802/44329159_0.shtml

Comment: From the photo, I'd say it means it's time to buy a new kettle!

Comment: Just found out: read it Yixing, from right to left, a place in Wuxi, Jiangsu province, a very hot place to be at the mo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a crushed aluminum kettle. It wrote 宜兴